# Disabling java next generation plugin in java 1.6 through regedit.exe

Tags: java

I am using java 1.6 version. I need to disable the java next generation plugin. I can do this in java control panel (checking/unchecking java next generation plugin manually).

But I need to automate the disabling java next generation plugin. So I followed the below process.
*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/JavaSoft/Java Plug-in/version* and made the *UseNewJavaPlugin* key value to *00000000*.

After doing this, in *control panel, java next generation plugin* is showing as disabled. But there is no effect. Why setting *UseNewJavaPlugin*  to 00000000 is not working?. Help me.

Comment: Flagged as off topic. This question should be asked at Server Fault.

Comment: Please give answer to my question

Comment: This is not a programming question. Ask your question at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) and you will more likely get an answer.